# How do I execute an event when a label is clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, label, code-behind

I want to add a click event handler when a WPF label is clicked. The idea is to do it code behind, because I´m generating the interface dynamically base on a document.

Comment: Sorry I was on on a hurry when I asked. (i´m still on one, but change the redaction a littlebit)
I want to create a click event for a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want a Label with a LeftMouseDown-event, which you would write from code?

In that case:

```
TestLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(TARGET);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned code behind, you can listen for the `Label's` `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event since a `Label` control does not have a Click event associated with it.

Example:

```
var label = new Label();
label.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += LabelMouseLeftButtonUp;    

// Handler
private void LabelMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```